# Adding new features in process template, TFS 2012

Tags: tfs-process-template

I'm using TFS 2012 and VS 2013. It's an existing project with few customization in process template. Due to this when I try to enable Code Review and Feedback features, it gives error.

Two questions:

1. How can I add these features in existing customized process
   template?
2. How can I download existing process template for
   customization? Process Template Manager only downloads the server version not the current project's version.

Another issue is my project's common process configuration file is not complete. below is the text im getting.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<CommonProjectConfiguration>
  <RequirementWorkItems />
  <TaskWorkItems />
</CommonProjectConfiguration>
```

There are few changes suggested on msdn but this file doesnt has much information.
How can i get valid file?

Below is the error list i'm getting;

[Error] TF400654: Unable to configure Planning Tools. The following element contains an error: RequirementWorkItems. TF400517: The value of this element is set to: Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.StoryPoints. You must set the value to a field that exists in all of the work item types that are defined in RequirementWorkItems. The field does not exist in the following work item types: User Story.

[Error] TF400654: Unable to configure Planning Tools. The following element contains an error: TypeFields/TypeField[type='Order']. TF400517: The value of this element is set to: Microsoft.VSTS.Common.StackRank. You must set the value to a field that exists in all of the work item types that are defined in RequirementWorkItems. The field does not exist in the following work item types: User Story.

[Error] TF400654: Unable to configure Planning Tools. The following element contains an error: TypeFields/TypeField[type='Activity']. TF400501: The value of this element is set to: Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Activity. You must set the value to a field that exists in the work item types that are defined in: TaskWorkItems. These work item types must also have the following field defined:  TypeFields/TypeField[type='RemainingWork']. The field does not exist in the following work item types: Task.

Comment: What error message are you getting? It could be useful to [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30107023/edit) your question to insert it.

Comment: Have you followed this post: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff432837.aspx ? If so, what problems do have. There are different approaches you can take depending on the exact problems - for our TFS, bringing the process template close enough inline to what TFS expects, hitting the button and then changing it back worked.

Comment: @DaveShaw, yes i've checked the link. Further i've updated the question with error list.

Comment: Do you have `StoryPoints` and `StackRank` fields in your `User Story` WITD and `Remaining Work` and `Activity` in your `Task` WITD. Try adding those and upgrading again.